# problem to install anything

Tags: 20.04, updates, uninstall, repository

I want to update and upgrade my server (ubuntu 20.04) but this error prevents the update:

```
404  Not Found [IP: 213.32.5.7 80]
Hit:9 http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.5/ubuntu bionic InRelease         
Hit:10 https://packagecloud.io/ookla/speedtest-cli/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://mariadb.mirrors.ovh.net/MariaDB/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Despite purging mariadb, the error still occurs. Can anyone help fix?

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached *End of Standard Support* last year](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/17/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts-began-on-may-31-2023/), and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (*cost maybe involved*) if you wish but community support (*such as this site*) no longer exists, though SE *Unix & Linux* allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Comment: When a release reaches EOL, third party mirrors & sources are free to *drop* support. Ubuntu 18.04 (*bionic*) is either EOL or EOSS depending on *architecture*; and your paste shows you're using either a EOL or EOSS release, thus errors were to be expected. Canonical provides extended support; but 3rd parties can elect not to.

Comment: You need to remove the 18.04 sources from your machine (*if you're using 20.04 or focal as stated; your pasted details all show 18.04 as your release; bionic being the codename for 18.04 where as focal is for 20.04*).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu is the official source for help (covering Desktop & Servers); this question has been closed to the duplicate on this site that contains ~same details presented differently.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your server cannot get upgrade information from http://mariadb.mirrors.ovh.net, so you should change to another mirror of MariaDB.
And you can get mirror-lists from https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mirror-sites-for-mariadb/.